# Call endpoint without argument but keep getting error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm just trying to call this endpoint from frontend:

```
let data = await client.get("/api/campaign/order");
```

But i keep getting `Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters` this error, i have no idea what should i do.

Because i'm not passing any argument to endpoint.

In backend:

```
router.route("/campaign/order").get(getOrder);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

originally was:

```
router.route("/campaign/:id").get(getOrderById);
router.route("/campaign/order").get(getOrder);
```

it will run the `getOrderById` function, just exchange the position and will work.

```
router.route("/campaign/order").get(getOrder);
router.route("/campaign/:id").get(getOrderById);
```